# Red and blinking areas on Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, hardware, malware

I have MacBook Air, 13 inches, macOS Sierra. 
Version 10.12.5

Sometimes when I put mouse over or click on some text - the area where mouse pointing getting red, sometimes this red area is getting bigger and started blinking and looks like those changings on screen are nor related to mouse.

It happened once a week and I could not tell what trigger this.
I was told by Mac representative that this is probably some sort of  malware.

But I have application Adware Medic and it doesn't detect any malware.

I think that it is possible hardware issue.

Any suggestion what cause this issue and how to fix it?

thanks.

//EDITED
Sometimes I have no red (see pictures below):

[image: no red in field]

[image: no red but green in field]

Comment: You should try [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mac/) as well as Adware Medic.

Comment: Could I use  Malwarebytes a free version?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to run some diagnostic tests yourself if you follow the Apple article [How to use Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) which also includes a link for machines introduced before 2013.

Worst case scenario: you have a graphics card issue. The in-built diagnostic tests may not be able to give a definite answer. An Apple Store or authorised repairer can diagnose this.

Before assuming the worst, I would recommend backing up your machine, running some diagnostic tests, and if you find no problems try re-installing the operating system. It is possible that re-installing your non-Apple applications one-by-one may reveal the culprit.

Comment: What do you mean by non-Apple applications?

Comment: The 'free' version is a trial version, but it installs files you need to later remove.

Comment: Re: @User's comment: By "non-Apple applications", I meant ones like Photoshop, Malwarebytes, and all the other applications which aren't from Apple or the Apple App Store. If it is NOT a hardware issue, my first step would be to (1) backup with TimeMachine (2) reinstall macOS (3) if the problem still occurs then wipe the disk, reinstall macOS and all the Applications and settings from TimeMachine, (4) if issues still happen then wipe again and install the applications one by one, starting with Apple s/w, then AppStore apps, then others, until you find which one is causing the problem.

Comment: I still have guarantee  on this Mac. Should I exercise this guarantee  telling what is the issue and let the store to fix it or should i proceed to do it myself.
I have back up but I've never done the next steps like reinstall OS... Is it complicated and/or time consuming?

Comment: Yes, If your machine is still under guarantee, then do exercise your rights and let the store fix it. Re-installing software is quite straightforward but can be fairly time-consuming (taking hours or possibly longer). If you want to look yourself before taking it to the store, try the Apple Diagnostic software as this only takes a few minutes or less than an hour. Please edit your question or add a comment saying exactly which model of Macbook Air it is. Some old or second-hand models might not have Apple Diagnostic software on them.

Comment: I've added version of this Mac. You think that  it is software/not native program issue... But on my very old mac(it was stolen), I've never had this red blinking screen and I don't install the new programs - just use back up from the old one.

Comment: If your OS is macOS 10.12.5 "Sierra" then your laptop is probably one of six Macbook Air models. It might be useful to identify which model it is. Useful WikiPedia article - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Air#Specifications I agree with you it could well be a hardware issue, and you should definitely run the Apple Diagnostics in the original answer. It is still possible that it is a software corruption issue, and you would want to rule that out if the hardware tests are inconclusive. If you are unwilling to do this then perhaps you should do as you suggest and exercise your guarantee.

Comment: Also useful to add: It would appear that you have not updated your macOS 10.12.5 system using Apple's automatic software update (the built-in App Store). So updating your machine to the latest build, macOS 10.12.6, is an easy first step.

Comment: I was told that better don't use the latest model since there are possible bugs that don't fixed yet. Should I ignore this suggestion and updated anyway?

Comment: How to see model on my Mac?

Comment: Your official model name is shown under the "About This Mac" option which is under the system's Apple Menu (top-left of your screen). The full model identifier, for example "Macbook Air 6,2" is show by the same AboutThisMac function when you click the button for "system report". Similar examples are in the Wikipedia article I gave you.

Comment: You misunderstood your friend's advice not to use the latest software. MacOS 10.12.5 has now been out for well over three months and is safe to upgrade to 10.12.6 which has been out for two months.

Comment: Your question was about possible causes. I answered your question and gave you information and some advice on how to proceed. If you are unwilling to take some basic actions, and unwilling to exercise your guarantee, then I do not think that I will be able to give you any more advice.
**If you wish to persist with your question on StackExchange, please post a fresh question in which you identify your system hardware, your system software, the symptoms you are experiencing, and list exactly what research you have done to identify the cause and what actions you have taken.**

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask