# How to follow the instruction to diagnose Mac?

Tags: ios, mac, macos

I am trying to diagnose my Mac Book Air, 10.12.5 follow link as below:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731

Regarding instruction(see on bottom), I need to hold D key.  I was trying to hold caps d or shift d and press them about 3 minutes ... but there is no a screen asking but regular desktop.

How to proceed?

thanks.

"Turn on your Mac, then immediately press and hold the D key on your keyboard. Keep holding until you see a screen asking ..."

Answer (score 1):

Its not a capital D, they would have specified "Shift-D" if in that case. Just hold **d** itself.

If it doesn't work, see the Learn More section at the bottom of that article.

Comment: d - doesn't work. On Learn more section: I don't create any firmware password in the first place , and option D doesn't start diagnose Mac....

Comment: What exact model is it? Some of the models do not have access to the internet-based diagnostics.

Comment: It is (I take from "About this Mac):
Model Name: MacBook Air
  Model Identifier: MacBookAir7,2
  Processor Name: Intel Core i7

Comment: I'd expect that model range to have Apple Diagnostics. What's wrong with it that you're trying to diagnose?

Comment: Sometime got red area that blinking:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297849/red-and-blinking-areas-on-mac

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of it?

Comment: It happened once a week sometimes even once at two weeks... When it happened it getting pretty bad all screen red and blinking in red - so i could not use comp. So, I'll try to do screen shot when it is happened again. But why I could not do diagnostic my Mac/maybe this is the part of the same problem?

Comment: No, the lack of the diagnostics would not be a reason. This may be a hardware issue, but not positive that diagnostics would notice it. Since its so intermittent, also try taking a photo of the screen with your camera or something.

Comment: I still have several months of guarantee but I would like to investigate myself before exercise this  since it could create another issue after repearing and it would not be guarantee after this. Also, I am not sure that I need to update operating system: I have pretty new Mac 10.12.5 already and I don't think that the operation system create a problem.